# Unfortunately, App has stopped (Android Development)

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I just started android development in 2 days and this is the error that I cannot solve "Unfortunately, [App] has stopped".

This is what I'm planning to do with the APP.

1. show the UI that will tell the user that by pressing ok  the app will start making a log file.
2. when the OK button is pressed, it will run in the background (don't need UI) and will wait for the notification from other app and will write the text from the notification to the log file.

This is my AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.notificationnotifier"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.notificationnotifier.GetNotification"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.notificationnotifier.MonitorNotification"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is GetNotification.java

```
public class GetNotification extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_notification);

        Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OKButton);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent getNotification = new Intent("com.example.notificationnotifier.MonitorNotification");
                startActivity(getNotification); 
            }
        }) ;

        Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        }) ;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }  
}
```

This is MonitorNotification.java

```
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

public class MonitorNotification extends AccessibilityService{

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  super.onServiceConnected();
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
          info.feedbackType = 1;
              info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
          info.notificationTimeout = 100; 
          setServiceInfo(info);
    }
}
```

This is the logcat
[updated]

```
02-04 10:31:17.947: E/Trace(1108): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 10:31:18.648: D/gralloc_goldfish(1108): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-04 10:31:21.128: D/AndroidRuntime(1108): Shutting down VM
02-04 10:31:21.148: W/dalvikvm(1108): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.notificationnotifier/com.example.notificationnotifier.MonitorNotification}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.notificationnotifier.MonitorNotification cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.notificationnotifier.MonitorNotification cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
02-04 10:31:21.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     ... 11 more
02-04 10:31:23.268: I/Process(1108): Sending signal. PID: 1108 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know now what the problem was, my friend told me that it should be startService not startActivity in the getNotification.java

the correct way to call it is

```
startService(getNotification);
```

not

```
startActivity(getNotification);
```

I'm extending AccesibilityService in the class in MonitorNotification.java. :D

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
Intent getNotification = new Intent("com.example.notificationnotifier.MonitorNotification");
```

by this one:

```
Intent getNotification = new Intent(GetNotification.this,
        MonitorNotification.class);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your manifest file:

> ```
>  <service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
>      android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
>  <intent-filter>
>      <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
>  </intent-filter>
>  . . .
> </service>
> ```

Comment: I added this inside <application> </application> but I still get "Unfortunately, App has stopped" error whenvever OK Button is pressed. anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration

An accessibility is declared as any other service in an AndroidManifest.xml but it must also specify that it handles the "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" Intent. Failure to declare this intent will cause the system to ignore the accessibility service. Additionally an accessibility service must request the BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE permission to ensure that only the system can bind to it. Failure to declare this intent will cause the system to ignore the accessibility service. Following is an example declaration:

```
 <service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
 </intent-filter>
 . . .
</service>
```

Comment: I added this inside <application> </application> but I still get "Unfortunately, App has stopped" error whenvever OK Button is pressed. anyway, thank you.

Comment: let try with this code ,,,,                                                                                                                                       Intent getNotification = new Intent(GetNotification.this,
        MonitorNotification.class);               Insted         ,,,,Intent getNotification = new Intent("com.example.notificationnotifier.MonitorNotification");

Comment: you need any other examples